# How to store while loop result to array using php

Tags: php

I have a mysql query which is return matching data from db. I need to store matching results data to `$autocompletiondata` like that :

```
$autocompletiondata =  array(
        1 => "shibbir",
        2 => "ahmed",
        3 => "babu",
        4 => "rahim",
        5 => "shakil",
);
```

**Sql query :**

```
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT cdid, family_name FROM contact_details WHERE     
family_name LIKE '%$term' ");

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $cdid = $res['cdid'];
    $fname = $res['family_name'];    
    $autocompletiondata =  array(
        $cdid => "$fname");
}
```

How can I store all matching data to associative array ? Plz help.

Comment: have a look at `array_push` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
$autocompletiondata = array();

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $cdid = $res['cdid'];
    $fname = $res['family_name'];    
    $autocompletiondata[$cdid] =  $fname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
  $cdid = $res['cdid'];
  $fname = $res['family_name'];    
  $autocompletiondata[$cdid] = $fname; // <== make this change to your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT cdid, family_name FROM contact_details WHERE     
family_name LIKE '%$term' ");

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $cdid = $res['cdid'];
    $fname = $res['family_name'];    
    $autocompletiondata[$cdid] = $fname;
}
```

And print the array with

```
print_r($autocompletiondata);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple just use the code below

```
$autocompletiondata =  array();
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT cdid, family_name FROM contact_details WHERE     
family_name LIKE '%$term' ");

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $cdid = $res['cdid'];
    $fname = $res['family_name'];    
    $autocompletiondata[$cdid] = $fname;
}
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Just set data to $autocompletiondata:

```
$autocompletiondata = array();
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $cdid = $res['cdid'];
    $fname = $res['family_name'];    
    $autocompletiondata [$cdid] = $fname;
}
```